# Why isn't any value being pushed to the 'res' string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

Its a program to add two binary numbers stored in strings and storing the result in a string.

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a = "11", b = "1";
    int i, j, carry = 0;
    string res;
    i = a.length() - 1;
    j = b.length() - 1;
    
    while (i >= 0 && j >= 0)
    {

        res.push_back((char)(a[i] + b[j] + carry) % 2);
        cout << "0";
        carry = (a[i] + b[j] + carry) / 2;

        i--;
        j--;
    }

    if (i > 0)
    {
        while (i >= 0)
        {
            res.push_back((char)(a[i] + 0 + carry) % 2);
            carry = (a[i] + 0 + carry) / 2;
        }
    }

    if (j > 0)
    {
        while (j >= 0)
        {
            res.push_back((char)(0 + b[j] + carry) % 2);
            carry = (0 + b[j] + carry) / 2;
        }
    }

    if (carry)
        res.push_back(carry);
    cout << endl
         << "-1";
    cout << endl
         << res;
}
```

output:

```
0
-1
1
```

Only 1 is pushed into res by the last `if(carry)` block. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add `+ '0'` to the values you're pushing.

Comment: Please, note that `0` (integer 0) is not the same like `'0'` (character `0`). The latter is (probably) [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoded where `'0'` == `48` and `'1'` == `49`. Nevertheless, you can do arithmetic operations with `'0'` and `'1'`. While reading `a[i]` and `b[j]` you may convert them into integrals `0` and `1` by subtracting `'0'`. While writing `res`, you have to add `'0'` to convert integrals to ASCII-encoded characters again.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the ASCII table, 49 is the ASCII value of char '1'. Thus it totally makes sense that the following:

```
res.push_back(carry);
```

...inserts '1' into res because at that point, carry's value is 49 and the variable carry is an integer. Thus, C++ inserts the character with the ASCII value 49, ie, 1.

So use this instead:

```
res += std::to_string(carry); // std::to_string converts many basic data types to std::string
```

The reason I am not using push_back here is because push_back can only insert a single character at one time. So you can use the += to add the contents of std::to_string(carry) to res.